# Firebase auth ui (com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth) problem

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I am working on firebase for my android app and I trying to implement firebase ui auth,
but sign-in intent gets suck. Some users reported the authentication picker activity is not loaded. 
When they tap on the button which launches the sign-in intent they get stuck.

Here is the code:

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.2'
```

```
public void createSignInIntent(String email)
    {
        
        // [START auth_fui_create_intent]
        // Choose authentication providers
        List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().setDefaultEmail(email).build()
                                                        );
        
        // Create and launch sign-in intent
        Intent signInIntent = AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                .setLogo(R.drawable.unnamed)
                .setAlwaysShowSignInMethodScreen(true)
                .build();
        signInLauncher.launch(signInIntent);
        // [END auth_fui_create_intent]

    }
```

I really have no idea what is going wrong here.
Thanks

Comment: Any error logs or stacktrace?

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem here using 8.0.2.
Just deactivate the Google Smart Lock.

```
 Intent signInIntent = AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                .setLogo(R.drawable.unnamed)
                .setAlwaysShowSignInMethodScreen(true)
                **.setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)**
                .build();
```

just update your app and give a try.